# List indexing in Python with duplicates

Tags: python, list

I've a numeric list containing several repeated items like such:

```
list1 = [40, 62, 0, 5, 8, 3, 62]
```

And a word list containing corresponding words:

```
list2 = ['cat', 'dog', 'turtle', 'fox', 'elephant', 'eagle', 'scorpion']
```

i.e. there are 40 cats, 62 dogs, etc.

Data above is merely for representation. Each value in `list1` is assigned an English dictionary word in `list2` corresponding to the indexes i.e. index 0 of the first list corresponds to index 0 of the second list.

How can I be sure that in a for-loop, if I call list1.index(i) where i is 62, it would return me eagle first, and then when the for-loop is executed again, it would skip the first 62 and proceed to the second 62 and return me scorpion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) both the items and iterate together to get the corresponding values together, like this

   ```
   >>> for number, word in zip(list1, list2):
   ...     print(number, word)
   ...     
   ... 
   40 cat
   62 dog
   0 turtle
   5 fox
   8 elephant
   3 eagle
   62 scorpion
   ```
2. Or you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the current index of the item, from the list being iterated and use the index to get the corresponding value from the other list

   ```
   >>> for index, number in enumerate(list1):
   ...     print("index :", index, number, list2[index])
   ...     
   ... 
   index : 0 40 cat
   index : 1 62 dog
   index : 2 0 turtle
   index : 3 5 fox
   index : 4 8 elephant
   index : 5 3 eagle
   index : 6 62 scorpion
   ```

Comment: Goodness me, thank you Sir, that works wonderfully. *hangs head in shame now* I will accept your answer as soon as the system allows me to.